# How to create a date calculation (add a number of days since a particular date and write a DD/MM/YYYY result)

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an MSSQL database with dates stored in integer type. The number is relevant to the number of days that have passed since 01/01/1970. I need an ASP.NET code that will take the integer from the database table and convert it into a date - add the number of days onto 01/01/1970 and echo the result in DD/MM/YYYY format. For example, if the number in the database was 3, the calculation script would produce 04/01/1970.

Comment: Come on; what have you tried? Have you tried to help yourself at all? This is exceptionally trivial. Please, put a bit of effort into helping yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Get value from database
int valueFromDatabase = 3;

DateTime jan1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
DateTime finalDate = jan1970.AddDays(valueFromDatabase);

string result = finalDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private static string GetConvertedDate(int numberOfDays)
{
   DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
   return defaultDate.AddDays(numberOfDays).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```